# Server component version number reporting and collecting - what is this called?

Tags: monitoring

What is the name given to software which reports versions for a given set of software components (libraries, applications, etc) on one or more servers, and the collection software that runs on a management or monitoring server?

Example: server `abacus` runs Nginx version 1.17.0, PHP version 7.2.2, MySQL Server version 5.7.5; server `badger` runs Nginx version 1.16.2, PHP version 7.3.2, MySQL Server version 5.7.7; server `cotton` runs Nginx version 1.15.10, PHP version 7.0.10, MySQL Server version 5.7.2; these servers communicate with server `zephyr` which collates the information for monitoring and management via some form of console.

Servers `abacus`, `badger` and `cotton` have an agent running on them. Server `zephyr` has a multi-server collection agent. What is the catch-all name for this type of software, please?

Please note: I am not looking for product recommendations, I would like to know what to search for to narrow down my choices based on what this is.

Thank you.

Comment: "Configuration Management Database" (aka CMDB) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: maybe "system inventory software" is the missing keyword here?

Comment: @DougDeden - thank you very much, this is getting me on the right track. I ended up at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_configuration_management_software after some keyword research, lots of software names I recognise but none I have experience with.

Comment: @neutrinus - thank you very much, you've given me lots of avenues to look into with that. A lot of the inventory software I'd looked at were limited to physical hardware assets, whereas there are some software-specific versions of the same to investigate.